# Intercepting TDS packets within application

Tags: sql-server-2005, c#-3.0

Is there a way to intercept TDS (Tabular Data Stream) packets within c# application.
I am intending to write an logging application with intercepted stream.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a Look at FreeTDS, a Complete Library written in C to handle the TDS Protocol. You could attach your hooks there.